# C++ 2D Arrays of an Object Constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, multidimensional-array

In my Dev C++, I am trying to create a 2D Array class that acts like a Grid.
But one of the problem is I am unsure what do for the constructor.

When I try to compile, I get the following errors:
In constructor 'Grid::Grid(int,int)':
'sqaures' is not a type
'yPos' cannot appear in a constant-expression
[Build Error] [grid.o] Error 1

Here is the Header File:

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H

using namespace std;

class Grid
{
      public:

      Grid(int xPos, int yPos);
      // Constructor
      // POST: Creates the squares of grid; (x,y) coordinates

      private:

      int squares;
      //2D Array
      //the squares; (x,y) coordinates of the grids      
};

#endif
```

And heres the .cpp file for the functions of grid.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grid.h"

using namespace std;

Grid::Grid(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    squares = new squares[xPos][yPos];
    //Trying to make squares into a 2D array, and turn the values into the arguments
    //into the the x,y coordinates 
}
```

My constructor in the .cpp files doesn't work and I'm unsure what to do. Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Not directly related to your question, but you should not have using declarations in your header (.h/.hpp) files.

e.g.:

```
using namespace std;
```

These belong in cpp files.

See [Herb Sutters GOTW (Guru of the Week) #53](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/053.htm) for reasons.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your code.
First of all, your member variable "squares" should be a **pointer to an int**, not an *int*:

```
int *squares;
```

Then, the following line will give an error:

```
squares = new squares[xPos][yPos];
```

What you really need is a block of memory for the 2D array:

```
squares = new squares[xPos * yPos];
```

Also, you should save the dimensions of this array in member variables (e.g., "sizeX" and "sizeY" )

Now, you have a block of memory which will hold a 2D array of squares. I usually overload the () operator for accessing an element in this array:

```
int &Grid::operator() (int x, int y)
{
      // you can check array boundaries here
      return squares[y + sizeX*x];
}
```

If you have problems with the operator stuff, just create a member function instead:

```
int Grid::get(int x, int y)
{
     // check array bounds
     return squares[y + sizeX*x];
}
void Grid::set(int x, int y, int value)
{
     // check array bounds
     squares[y + sizeX*x] = value;
}
```

Finally, you need a destructor to free the memory:

```
Grid::~Grid()
{
     delete [] squares;
}
```

This is how I like to do it (the "C-with-classes" style). In another answer, David Norman gives a good "Standard C++" way of implementing your class.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid lots of memory issues, use a vector of vectors.

In the header

```
class Grid
{
    ...
    std::vector< std::vector<squares> > squares;
    ...
}
```

In the .cpp

```
Grid::Grid(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    squares.resize(xPos);
    for (int i = 0; i < xPos; i++) {
        squares[i].resize(yPos);
    }
}
```

Later on:

```
squares[2][3] = square(...);
```

Or use a vector of vector of smart pointers if you want to new the squares.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you got the code right? Your squares is defined as an int, not as an int**?
I'm not sure how you're getting this to compile....

EDIT:
The error message you are getting results from you defining squares as an int. Therefore, it can only take a single integer number. Your constructor is trying to assign a whole array into it. Are you familiar enough with pointers, arrays, dereferencing and all that stuff? A two dimensional array is generally tricky.

If you write your 2D array well, you can actually use a single array, and just map two-dimensional addresses into a single index.

Comment: He isn't according to his question.

Comment: I misunderstood his compiler message. I think that he forgot a period somewhere in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Grid::Grid(int xPos, int yPos) {
    squares = new squares[xPos][yPos];
    //Trying to make squares into a 2D array, and turn the values into the arguments
    //into the the x,y coordinates 
}
```

That's of course wrong. you have to do `new int[xPos][yPos]` . The operator requires you to give it a type. But still then, you are not finished. `yPos` must be known at compile time. In your example it isn't. The reason is because it becomes part of the type that is returned by the new expression:

```
int (*squares)[yPos] = new int[xPos][yPos];
```

As types are static, yPos can't be determined at runtime. What you really want is a vector of int. But i figure you want to do the memory management yourself, because you want to learn the language rules. So go with this:

1. Make squares a `int*`: `int *squares;`
2. Change the line in the constructor into `squares = new int[xPos * yPos];`
3. Add a line like `delete[] squares;` into your destructor.
4. Add a copy constructor and copy assigment operator that copies along your memory when your instance is copied.
5. add a member-function like the below:

Code:

```
int & get(int x, int y) { return squares[y * yPos + x]; }
```

Which will give you the integer at the given position. Of course, you can also overload `operator[]` to have natural access using 2d indices:

```
class Grid {
    struct proxy {
        proxy(int *row):row(row) { }
        int & operator[](int x) {
            return row[x];
        }
        int * row;
    };

    int * squares;
public:
    proxy operator[](int y) {
        return proxy(squares + yPos * y); 
    }
};
```

The outer index will select the row, the inner will select the column. If you got to manage the memory right, you can change to better solutions. For your task, `boost::multi_array` is ideal: [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

#### Other problems

Never do `using namespace std;` in a header file. The reason is that all code that indirectly or directly include that file will automatically also have that line included and thus see *all of std::*. Name conflicts will happen as soon as code tries to reference names that also happen to be defined by the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work:

```
squares = new squares[xPos][yPos];
```

You need:

```
squares = new (int*)[xPos];
for (int x = 0; x < xPos; ++x) {
     squares[x] = new int[yPos];
}
```

And personally, that's the wrong way to do it. I prefer

```
class Grid {

     class Row {
         int* row; // this is a pointer into Grid::grid
         int size; // this equals Grid::col_count and is only here for bounds checking
     public:
         Row(int s, int* r) : size(s), row(r) {}

         int& operator[](int col) {
             if (col >=0 && col < size) return row[col];
             throw OutOfBoundsException();
         }
     };

     int row_count, col_count;
     int* grid;
     Row* rows;

  public:
     Grid(int x, int y) : row_count(x), col_count(y) {
         rows = new (Row*)[row_count];
         grid = new int[row_count*col_count];
         int* grid_walk = grid;
         for (int i = 0; i < row_count; ++i) {
             rows[i] = new Row(col_count, grid_walk);
             grid_walk += col_count;
         }
     }
     ~Grid() { delete[] rows; delete[] grid; }

     Row& operator[](int row) {
         if (row ?= 0 && row < row_count) return rows[row];
         throw OutOfBoundsException();
     }

     int rows() const { return row_count; }
     int cols() const { return col_count; }

};

Grid checkers(8,8);

for (r = 0; r < checkers.row_count(); ++r) {
    for (c = 0; c < checkers.col_count(); ++c) {
        if ((r + c) % 2 == 1) checkers[r][c] = -1; // red space
        else if (r < 3) checkers[r][c] = 1; // player 1
        else if (r >= 5) checkers[r][c] = 2; // player 2
        else checkers[r][c] = 0; // open square
    }
}
// etc.
```

Hopefully there aren't too many typos.

Answer (score 1):

As per [David Norman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388258/c-2d-arrays-of-an-object-constructor/388278#388278), use `std::vector`. However there is a bug in his answer, the vector should be declared as follows:

```
class Grid
{
...

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > squares;
};
```

You can also initialise it using the vector constructor that takes a size and value:

```
Grid::Grid(int xPos, int yPos)
:   squares( xPos, std::vector<int>( yPos, 0 ) )
{
}
```