# 2D Std::vector of a given class

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm trying to use a vector to store x and y coordinates of certain data in my vector. I assumed the following would work but that is not the case. I have spent a lot of time searching hoping to get it to work but in vain. I appreciate any help whatsoever.

```
class A {

public:
  A(size_t x, size_t y); //ctor

  };
```

If I want to create a vector of type class A, so 2D, why is

```
 std::vector<A> vec(10); not working? 

void count(size_t x, size_t y) {
    vec.at(x,y);
}

   ERROR: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Board>::at(size_t, size_t&)
   note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Since class A's constructor has 2 variables, shouldn@t my vector of type A take 2 variables as well? 
If not, what is the correct way of getting a 2d vector of class A such that I can call the .at()-function at x,y and get whatever is stored there?

Comment: `std::vector` requires a default constructor for the contained class items.

Comment: You could just have a vector of `std::pair`  s rather than rolling your own.

Comment: The vector has to be of type A, how  would this work with std::pair? 
std::vector<std::pair<A>> is not a pair, and std::vector<std::pair<A*, A>> vec2; would need two pairs of (x,y) each, right?

Comment: @InfoGirl I'm under the impression that you just a vector of grouped `size_t` variables? `std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> vec;`.

Comment: `at` takes the index into the vector, not the value of the contents.

Comment: also `vec.at(x,y);` beware, the comma operator is not doing what you think.

Comment: Also, you call this 2D, but it is just a 1D vector of pairs of coordinates.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are trying to implement something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388258/c-2d-arrays-of-an-object-constructor ?

Answer (score 2):

This vector overload:

```
std::vector<A> vec(10);
```

makes 10 copies of type `A` by calling `A`'s default constructor. Since you didn't provide a default constructor an error occurs. Provide the default constructor:

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
};
int main() {
    std::vector<A> v(10);
}
```

or use an appropriate constructor as a second parameter:

```
class A {
public:
    A(size_t x, size_t y) {
    // your code
    }
};
int main() {
    std::vector<A> v(10, A(1, 2));
}
```

That being said, don't confuse the vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> v;
```

with a simple constructor taking two parameters or a simple class having two data members.